# Limit which classes can call another class by namespace or interface

Tags: php, oop

Is it possible to programmatically limit access to a class methods from another class?

I am working with an MVC framework which is made up of modules. Modules exist in their own namespace and namespace exactly mimics folder structure. A module contains, at least, a class that is an instance of the module interface but usually a controller and a model. Most of them also contain lib classes unique to that module.

For what we need this is quite a sweet setup. A module obviously needs to access the public methods of its own namespaced classes but that means other modules can do that too and they should only be calling the module class public methods.

Can a class method's scope be limited to a single namespace (or by interface) or is this a step too much for PHP's current level of object oriented implementation?